# Display text differently on div

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which displays text vertically.[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/FWzAS/32/)

```
    <div id="btn-toggle-menu">

         M
         e
         n
         u

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #btn-toggle-menu {
       top:0;
       left:0;
       width:20px;
       cursor:pointer;
       font-weight:bold;
       background-color:#ccc;
       text-align:center;
       white-space: pre;
    }
```

O/P:
[image: I want the text like the first option]

I want the text to be displayed like the one which points to Required menu text. Can someone give me a demo fiddle?

Comment: What's your question???

Comment: think you need to look up css3 transforms

Comment: Just to be sure, the answer you marked as solution doesnt work in FF25. Mine and Sandip's do.

Comment: Oops!! I didn't test it in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/37/)

**css**

```
#btn-toggle-menu {

    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    height:500px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    white-space: pre;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#inner-div
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a span with this class (or change css selector), this should do it

```
.textWrapper{
    background: #FFF;
    display: inline-block; /* inline doenst work, block seems to make it switch CC<->CCW */

    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* FireFox*/
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);  /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);  /* Opera */
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE9 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";   /* IE8 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);/* The way it should work: */
}
```

This will probably turn the wrong way, just change it to -90, or 270 degrees.
 Bear in mind that IE8 doesnt do very will in odd numbers (like 67), stick to 45degree steps to avoid that
I did not add code for IE7 or older, those should be burned without mercy.

Very simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DqTe6/1/ . This doesnt improve the font. You might need to go with an image.
Normally I prefer text over image, but the text 'menu' has no SEO value whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">
    <p class="text">Menu</p> 
</div>

.text
{
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
   filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
/* IE6,IE7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; 
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VmH5g/

Comment: Well, I checked again, it really doesnt do anyting here.

Comment: You could ask a bit more polity, but besides that, the text is as if there is no css, no screeny needed :)

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox because you missed "-" in front of moz, it should be -moz-transform...

Comment: sorry it happened mistakenly. Actually I have not missed it on my html page. So when I copied to fiddle that time I had missed the " - "

Comment: I think you can Understand me as developer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg">
    <div id="btn-toggle-menu">Menu</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#btn-toggle-menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    width: 40px;
    /* white-space: pre;*/    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   /* Firefox */
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   /* IE */
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   /* Opera */
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   /* Internet Explorer */
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
.bg{background-color:#ccc;height:100px;width:20px;position:relative}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/35/

Refer http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Comment: You should not use `position: abosulute` if you dont have to. This situation only needs a margin. Absolute slows the browser down (talking millisecs!), and if you use absolute allot, you will notice it. Also, it makes code more difficult to work with, the parent has to be relative etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);

-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

[Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/36/)

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/20/)**

use belo `CSS` in your code:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ff-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..
Slightly modified version of @Martijn's answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/SmtCS/

**CSS**

```
.textWrapper{
background: #FFF;
/* FireFox*/
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
/* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform:rotate(270deg);
/* IE9 */
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);
/* IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu" class="btn textWrapper">M e n u </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jWJMn/

```
.element {
   -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
   -o-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
   -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) ;
   transform: rotate(270deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
    background-color:yellow;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;

}
```